# Original ArrayList being modified when another ArrayList set equal to it is changed

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using an `ArrayList` for a program, called `wordList`. I have a separate `ArrayList` for another method, called `smallestWords`. I do "`smallestWords = arrayList`" in order to have a copy of `wordList` that I can modify without affecting the original. However, whenever I modify `smallestWords`, it also modifies `wordList`, which is causing me issues. I'm assuming it's because setting `smallestWords` equal to `wordList` just sets it equal to that memory location, since it's an abstract data type, and gets passed by reference.

How can I make it so I get a copy of the data without being able to modify it? If you want to see the actual code for the program just ask.

Comment: add you code for right answer.

Comment: Are you actually copying the list or are you just assigning another variable to it?

Answer (score 2):

You are not copying  with `smallestWords = arrayList` . You are just assigning the same `ArrayList` to `smallestWords`

You should use below method to copy:

```
List<String> smallestWords = new ArrayList<String>(arrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a copy of an `ArrayList`, you can use:

```
ArrayList smallestWords = new ArrayList(wordList);
```

(insert generic type parameters as appropriate)